# Number of Distinct Colors Found After Drawing N Balls from a Bag of Colored Balls

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider a situation with a bag containing an infinite number of colored balls. It is known that there are K distinct colors in the bag. Balls are drawn from the bag. Balls with duplicate colors are discarded.  After drawing N balls how many of the N are unique?

Comment: What do you  mean by unique balls?

Comment: Unique, meaning balls with distinct color.

Comment: Do all colors have the same probability?

Comment: Yes, you can assume the colors are all equally probable.

Comment: Can this post be helpful? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317146/expected-number-of-different-colors

Comment: Thank you, that looks like a more general version of my question.

Comment: There is a difference, the other question is for drawing balls with replacement.

Comment: If there's an infinite number of balls in the bag, do you think replacing or not replacing is going to make a difference?

Comment: My bad, I  was originally thinking of the model where there is a very large number of balls in the bag and then opted for the simpler model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as if there are an infinity of balls, if you replace the balls you draw, there is a 0 chance that you will draw them a second time. So, replacing them or not is irrelevant.

I don't think it exists a closed expression for what you are searching for.

You can calculate the result using a recursive expression.
if you consider the probability of drawing m distinct colors among n drawn balls P(n,m)
Then you have that :
$P(n,m)=P(n-1,m)\frac{m}{K}+P(n-1,m-1)\frac{K-m+1}{K}$

So as P(1,1)=1 and P(1,n)=0 for n>1

then $P(2,1)=P(1,1)*\frac{1}{K}$
$P(2,2)=P(1,1)*\frac{K-1}{K}$

And so on...

Comment: Interesting, but I need the expected number of colors after N trials.

Comment: You can get it by computing $\sum_i (E(i))$. So the calculus is of complexity O(n). Do you think from the context where you extract your problem (for instance problem from a book) that there exists closed form solution ? It is possible that there is not such thing.

Comment: I see your point. I have been using $E(N) = N(1- (1- 1/k)^N)$ as an approximation for the finite case as $(1- (1- 1/k)^N)$ gives the expectation of finding a specific color after N trials.