# How Much of a Distribution has One Seen After N Samples with Replacement?

Tags: probability, statistics, sampling

I frequently run into this question while modeling processes.  I am wondering if there is a general solution or approximation.

*The question I run into is*: For a given distribution with a finite number of points, how much of the distribution have I explored after viewing $n$ samples with replacement? In other words, I have a box of balls with $n$ colors. The frequency of each color is given by a function $F(n)$. After sampling the distribution t times with replacement how many of the $n$ colors have been exposed in expectation?

There is an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317146/expected-number-of-different-colors). Using the given solution one could divide the distribution into $n$ discrete points to get the probability of each point and perform the given summation to arrive at the expected number of different colors seen.

**Q**: Is there a way to go directly from the continuous function $F(n)$ to an approximate or exact solution for the discrete case without the need for the summation given in [the above solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317146/expected-number-of-different-colors)?

Comment: What is the function, F?

Comment: Is $F(n)$ the probability of drawing the $n$th colour in a single sample?  Or is $F(n)$ the number of unique colours observed after $n$ samples with replacement? Or something else?

Comment: @Henry, Benedict  $F(n)$ is the probability of drawing the $n$th color in a single sample; typically based on a chi-square distribution, power lognormal distribution etc. such that the area under the curve is approximately 1.

Comment: If $F(n)$ is the probability of drawing the $n$th colour in a single sample, with $\sum_n F(n)=1$ then the expected number of unique colours after $m$ draws is $ \sum_n \left(1-\left(1-F(n)\right)^m \right)$ as the answer to your linked question suggests.  You will not be able to avoid the sum or some equivalent way of combining the $F(n)$ except in special cases, such as when they are all equal

Comment: @Henry Thank you! You have lifted the nagging feeling that there was a better way.