# Expected number of different colors of balls obtained before getting the first red ball

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, expectation

> An urn contains red, green, and blue balls. Balls are chosen randomly with replacement (each time, the color is noted and then the ball is put back). Let $r,\ g,\ b$ be the probabilities of drawing a red, green, blue ball, respectively $(r + g + b = 1)$.
>
> (a) Find the expected number of balls chosen before obtaining the first red ball, not including the red ball itself.
> (b) Find the expected number of different colors of balls obtained before getting the first red ball.
> (c) Find the probability that at least $2$ of $n$ balls drawn are red, given that at least $1$ is red.

I could solve (a) (Geom$(r)$) and (c) (Bin$(n,r)$), but not be able to know where to start in (b). I don't even know what the number of different colors refer to. Isn't it the same like (a)? I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317146/expected-number-of-different-colors) but it's very general and abstract. May you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For (b)

- the probability of seeing blue before red is $\frac{b}{b+r}$
- the probability of seeing green before red is $\frac{g}{g+r}$

so the expected number of distinct colours seen before red is simply $\frac{b}{b+r}+\frac{g}{g+r}$

Comment: Thanks for your answer :). Actually I'm still confused what distinct colors refer to. Like, every 1 green and 1 blue is considered 1 distinct color?

Comment: Or is it like if we obtain 5 green balls and 2 blue balls before the first red, then we have two distinct colors before the first red?

Comment: @AbduMagdy: the second of your two comments

Answer (score 1):

If $D$ denotes the number of different *colors* of balls contained before getting the first red ball then $D$ takes values in $\{0,1,2\}$.

Then: $$\mathsf ED=\mathsf P(D=1)+2\mathsf P(D=2)=\mathsf P(D=1)+2(1-\mathsf P(D=0)-\mathsf P(D=1))=$$$$2-2\mathsf P(D=0)-\mathsf P(D=1)=2-2r-\mathsf P(D=1)$$

Can you find $\mathsf P(D=1)$ yourself?

Comment: Thanks for your answer :). Is $P(D=1)=(1-r)$?

Comment: Why do you think so? It is $gr+ggr+gggr+\cdots+br+bbr+bbbr+\dots$. Do you see why?

Comment: Yes I see. Because all of these are disjoint events and they all represent 1 distinct color before the 1st red ball, right?

Comment: That is correct.