# Expected number of different colors, law of iterated expectations

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, expected-value, balls-in-bins

I am working on the following problem:

An urn contains red, green, and blue balls. Balls are chosen randomly with
replacement (each time, the color is noted and then the ball is put back.) Let $r$, $g$, $b$
be the probabilities of drawing a red, green, blue ball respectively $(r + g + b = 1)$.

Find the expected number of different colors of balls obtained before getting the
first red ball.

I have written my attempt below. My answer doesn't agree with the solution so would appreciate if anyone could point out my mistake.

---

Let $N$ be the number of colors that are seen before the first red ball, and $X$ be the number of balls taken out before the first red one (not counting the red one). Then $N$ can be $0$, $1$ or $2$, and 
$$P(N=1 | X)=b^X+g^X$$
because for $N$ to be 1 we need all $X$ balls to be blue or all $X$ balls to be red.

Similarly, 
$$P(N=2|X)=\sum_{k=1}^{X-1}{X\choose k}b^kg^{X-k}=(b+g)^X-b^X-g^X.$$

Then we can calculate $E(N)$ using the law of iterated expectations
\begin{align}
E(N)=E(E(N|X))&=E(0\cdot P(N=0|X)+1\cdot P(N=1|X)+2\cdot P(N=2|X))\\
&=E(b^X+g^X+2((b+g)^X-b^X-g^X)=E(2(b+g)^X-b^X-g^X)
\end{align}

$X$ is distributed $\sim$ Geo(r), so using LOTUS we can find 
$$E(b^X)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty b^k (1-r)^kr=\frac{r}{1-b(1-r)}$$
and similarly we can find $E(g^X)$ and $E((g+b)^X)$ to get a final answer
$$E(N)=\frac{2r}{1-(b+g)(1-r)}-\frac{r}{1-b(1-r)}-\frac{r}{1-g(1-r)}.$$

This doesn't agree with the solution given or this post [Expected number of different colors of balls obtained before getting the first red ball](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2723305/expected-number-of-different-colors-of-balls-obtained-before-getting-the-first-r). I understand the answer given in that post but I can't find the mistake in this alternative method.

Comment: Not following.  What does $b^X+g^X$ mean? If, say, $X=0$ then how is this expression anything other than $2$?  But $2$ can't be a probability...  And if $X>0$ then it is even larger.

Comment: $P(N=1|X)=b^X+g^X$ is shorthand for $P(N=1|X=x)=b^x+g^x$, it's a conditional probability. I agree that equation only holds for $X>0$ which is not something that I have taken into account. I think if $X>0$ it won't be even larger though, since $g$ and $b$ are themselves between $0$ and $1$ (they are the probabilities of getting a green or a blue ball rather than the numbers of balls of those colours).

Comment: I have no idea what that means.  Are you saying that $P(N=1\,|,X=1)=b+g$?  Why would that be?  Isn't $P(N=1\,|\,X=1)=1$?